# Where does Liferay keep the system bundle?

Tags: liferay, osgi, osgi-bundle, liferay-7, liferay-7.1

I'm looking for the `jar` for the `com.liferay.blogs.service.permissions` package. I've managed to track it down to an export of the system bundle, i.e. bundle `0`. But I can't figure out where Liferay keeps this bundle.

My question, then, is as follows: where does Liferay DXP deployment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Liferay keeps bundles for the OSGi framework at the `osgi` directory.

The blogs bundle is actually inside a wrapping file (Liferay package) inside the `osgi/marketplace`

ps: you can extract those packages by the way, similar to jars, on to this date at least, they are just compressed files.